# How to show $\sup_{x,y \neq 0} \frac {x^TAy} {\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}=\sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|Ay\|_2} {\|y\|_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I can figure out that the maximum of singular value: $\sigma_{max}=\sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|Ay\|_2} {\|y\|2}$ for a real matrix A of $m \times n$.
But I cannot achieve that:
$$\sup_{x,y \neq 0} \frac {x^TAy} {\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}=\sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|Ay\|_2} {\|y\|_2}$$
Can you help?

Comment: Can you assume that $A$ is "diagonal" (in the sense that $\Lambda$ in the SVD $A=U\Lambda V$ is diagonal)?

Comment: Sorry. But I can't understand what you said. Is not $\Lambda$ diagonal in SVD $A=U \Lambda V^T$?

Comment: In the special case $m=n$, can you assume $A$ is diagonal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, 
$$\sup_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2=1}\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v}=\|\mathbf{v}\|_2.$$

By letting $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{x}/\|\mathbf{x}\|_2$ and $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{Ay}/\|\mathbf{y}\|_2$, we immediately arrive at
$$\sup_{\mathbf{x,y} \neq 0} \frac {\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Ay}} {\|\mathbf{x}\|_2\|\mathbf{y}\|_2}=\sup_{\mathbf{y} \neq 0} \frac{\|\mathbf{Ay}\|_2} {\|\mathbf{y}\|_2}.$$